# How do I fix a corrupted XLS file?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file that has recently become corrupted.  It was created back in 2006 and I was wondering if anyone knows of a quick and easy way to extract the data.

The exact error message is:

> [filename.xls]: File format is not valid

The question: is there a way I can manually repair or at least extract the data from the file?