# Why recovered .xls and .doc files show as symbols?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, data-recovery, openoffice, xls

I formatted an NTFS drive (and re-installed windows) which had some important .doc and .xls files, I used 2 recovery software and both recovered my files but seem to be corrupt, when opened they appear as symbols something like this

> —‰iÄá–§
>   ê ±Í|º‚^qêO
>   É¬

I tried opening them using Open Office it showed me a character set option, and I tried all the character sets the symbols change but no text appears, I also tried an excel repair software which didn't help at all but showed **OLE header corrupt**.

So is there a chance to get back the data inside these files ?

Comment: What recovery software did you use?

Comment: @nixda I tried, stellar phoenix and then getdataback, both found the files and copies of both programs show the same.

Comment: Have you found [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/593760/how-do-i-fix-a-corrupted-xls-file/603633#603633)? Also, maybe its worth a try to test some more [recovery tools](http://dottech.org/113185/windows-review-best-free-file-data-recovery-programs/) (different techniques)

Comment: Could you please send a copy of one of the file ?

Comment: @edi9999 this is one of the recovered files https://www.dropbox.com/s/hs4eml6h8x9tggm/recovered.xls